# .NET Core 3.1 Authentication cookie isn't deleted if I use 'options.Events.OnSigningIn'

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

Please I need your input.

The authentication cookie doesn't get deleted on `.HttpContext.SignOutAsync();`

The issue appears **ONLY** if I add this:

```
options.Events.OnSigningIn = (o) =>
                {
                    o.Options.Cookie.Domain = o.HttpContext.Request.Host.Host;
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                };

options.Events.OnSigningOut = (o) =>
                {
                    o.Options.Cookie.Domain = o.HttpContext.Request.Host.Host;
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                };
```

If I comment those out then everything works fine.

My question: is this some sort of bug and I have to report it to Microsoft? Or did I do something wrong?

Here is how authentication is added:

```
services
      .AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
      .AddScheme<ProxyAuthenticationOptions, ProxyAuthenticationSchemeHandler>(ProxyAuthentication.AuthenticationScheme, options => { })
      .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = (o) =>
                {
                    o.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                };
                options.Events.OnRedirectToAccessDenied = (o) =>
                {
                    o.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                };
                options.Events.OnSigningIn = (o) =>
                {
                    o.Options.Cookie.Domain = o.HttpContext.Request.Host.Host;
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                };
                options.Events.OnSigningOut = (o) =>
                {
                    o.Options.Cookie.Domain = o.HttpContext.Request.Host.Host;
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                };

                if (cookieSettings.LocalizationCookieExpiration.TryConvertToTimeSpan(out TimeSpan expiration))
                {
                    options.ExpireTimeSpan = expiration;
                    options.Cookie.MaxAge = expiration;
                }

                options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = cookieSettings.SecureCookies ? CookieSecurePolicy.Always : CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest;
                options.Cookie.Path = "/";
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
                SameSiteMode sameSiteMode = Enum.Parse<SameSiteMode>(cookieSettings.SameSite);
                options.Cookie.SameSite = sameSiteMode;
                options.Cookie.Name = cookieSettings.AuthenticationCookieName;
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in here `o.Options.Cookie.Domain = o.HttpContext.Request.Host.Host;`

Should be like this: `o.CookieOptions.Domain = o.HttpContext.Request.Host.Host;`